# Combine two folder in one src together

Tags: eclipse, smartgwt

[Code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oUG3.png) I am required to separate src into two folders which is java and resources. However when I compile the code, I notice that java folder runs without resources.
Is there anyway that I can link java folder together with resources folder .

Comment: What do you mean by _"when I compile the code"_? Do you use Ant (in the screenshot there is a `build.xml` file) or do you use Eclipse for compiling (with separate output folders per source folder)?

Comment: I use eclipse to compile it but only one output for two folder and when I compile it, there is an error message which states that " the server failed to return a formatted response at all". I think the issue is that the java folder does not interact with the resources folder.

Comment: In the _Navigator_ view, you can check if your assumption is correct and the output folder (which is by default the `bin` folder) contains also the files of `src/resources`.

Comment: this serves as a big help as before this I dont know there is a way to check my output folder, thank you very much howlger. However, my problem still persist which your method helps me to confirm that the issue does not caused by the two separate folder. Thank you very much howlger

Comment: I finally manage to solve this issue, the problem actually is my hibernate-mapping points to different place and my client-side cannot retrieve the data.